aws lambda 60s timeout when executing copy command from S3 to redshift due to waiting in WLM queue

I have an S3 bucket in which events land from user devices

there is an aws lambda which watches the bucket and executes COPY command from the bucket to a Redshift cluster

I have been experiencing errors in the lambda from time to time causing missing events in the data warehouse

Investigation and findings:

the "error" is due to the fact that the lambda times out at 60s
upon looking further, I noticed the COPY command queries are in the WLM queue (using auto WLM)
sometimes the query exceeds 60s in the queue, causing the failed lambda, causing missing events in the warehouse
the data itself is certainly not large enough to take more than 60s to copy (i checked)


my (failed) experiment:

I removed all async, await in the lambda (using nodejs)
despite the final console.log at the final return, the lambda hangs around for the duration it takes for the redshift COPY command to finish execution
my suspicion is that the TCP socket is still dangling till redshift returns with the response


Pain points with the above problem:

its increasing cost when lambda runtimes are just waiting, doing nothing
I have missing events in the warehouse


alternatives to consider:

switch to a specific WLM queue instead of auto-WLM (dont know how this will impact other workloads/concurrency scaling)
??? help?



